# SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE in firefox for react app with HTTPS=true & HOST=xxx

Tags: reactjs, firefox, https, ssl-certificate, create-react-app

I have a `SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE` error in firefox for a react application created with `create-react-app` when I specify a custom `HOST` and `SSL=true`

To reproduce the issue:

1. create a new react app

   ```
   npx create-react-app testssl
   ```
2. add a `.env` file with

   ```
   HTTPS=true
   HOST=test.local
   ```
3. ensure `test.local` map to `127.0.0.1` in your hosts file

   ```
   # "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
   127.0.0.1 test.local
   ```
4. launch the application

   ```
   npm run start
   ```

In chrome I have a `security error` but I can bypass it

[image: error in chrome]

In firefox I have a `SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE` and I can't find a way to bypass it :

[image: Firefox error]

Is there any way to bypass this error for firefox ?

I have this error with windows environment, not sure about linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up adding my own self signed certificate to the project.

To generate the certificates I use the following openssl command :

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -keyout test.local.key -out test.local.crt -days 4000 -new -nodes
```

and in my `.env` file I added the following line

```
SSL_CRT_FILE=./test.local.crt
SSL_KEY_FILE=./test.local.key
HTTPS=true
HOST=test.local
```

but I'm still not sure why firefox doesn't accept the certificate generated by `creat-react-app`